# How to expand the hotbox area of a WPF element

Tags: c#, wpf

I've got a custom panel element that is a bunch of dotted lines. The problem is, if I want to mouse over, not only do you have to be right over the line, but you can't be in-between the dots.

Is there a way to create a custom hotbox area that will trigger even if my mouse isn't exactly over the element? My only solution is to create larger solid transparent lines and use that as a hit box.

Comment: Your current solution is the right approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Edit:* I just realised that your lines might not be horizontal / vertical but with arbitrary orientation. In that case my solution would not jield the desired result and using transparent lines like you suggested yourself would be a good option.

You can use a container element like `border` that contains your line but is bigger. Then you implement the desired behviour on your container element and not on the line itself.

```xml
<Border Grid.Row="1" Height="2">
    <!-- handle interaction behaviour here -->
    <Line Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1, 1" X2="1000"/>
</Border>
```